# What does each SPECIAL stat in Fallout Shelter do?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Besides its workplace uses, like Charisma in Living Quarters, Strength in Power Generators, Agility in Diners.

Do we know if Endurance increases HP in the Dwellers, or that strength helps in melee damage / survivability in the wastelands? And Perception?

Answer (score 130):

Do note that nothing has been made official, and this is a compilation of observations/hypotheses.

### Strength

- Vault:

  - Decreased timer while working in power plants
- Wastes:

  - Needed to pry open lockers and boxes.
  - May also affect damage done by guns.
  - May increase a Dwellers capacity.

### Perception

- Vault:

  - Hit chance in combat
  - Decreases water production timer of the Water Treatment and Water Purification rooms
- Wastes:

  - Find stuff like abandoned buildings
  - Critical attack cross hairs expand and contract slower, making it easier to deal maximum damage  (×5) with a critical attack.

### Endurance

- General:

  - [Health points gained on level up](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235425/does-endurance-over-10-increase-hp-gain-per-level) (does not increase hp retroactively, max out endurance to 10+7 outfit and then start leveling to get maximum health)
  - Resist radiation and damage (11 Endurance = immune to radiation)
- Vault:

  - Food and water production timers of the Nuka-Cola bottler room.

### Charisma

- Vault:

  - Improved fertility. (Reduced time to get pregnant.)
  - Decreases production timer in Radio room.
- Wastes:

  - Also chance of befriending people in the wastes (Gives the xp but no damage taken)
  - Interaction with groups of slaves

### Intelligence

- Vault:

  - Med-bay (Stims and Radaway) production timers
- Wastes

  - Heal/help people

UPDATE:

- Vault/Wastelands:

  - also increases Exp gain (for level and Special stat increasing), extinguishing fire

### Agility

- Vault:

  - Food production timer of the Diner and Garden rooms.
  - Increases attack speed.
- Wastes:

  - Run away from unwinnable fights taking less damage

### Luck

- Vault:

  - Decreases chance of rush failure.
  - Increases amount of caps earned when resources collected from a production room (also increases chance to earn those caps)
  - Increases critical bar fill up rate.
- Wastes

  - Amount of loot found outside vault

Further reading and sources:

- Reddit: [/r/foshelter What does each attribute do?](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3a1urb/what_does_each_attribute_do/)
- Reddit: [/r/foshelter Guys, power armor doesn't give any defensive stats in the wastes. ...](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3afgdb/guys_power_armor_doesnt_give_any_defensive_stats/)
- [Loading screen tips from Fallout Shelter for iOS](http://www.docpop.org/2015/06/loading-screen-tips-from-fallout-shelter-for-ios/)

---

### Tip:

- I set my shelter that way, to have the medbay spread in the vault to handle fire faster.
- the difference in having 1 or 2 intelligence is that a dweller with 2 intelligence levels up in half the time
- queuing my new matured dwellers to go to school so they get intelligence 2 or 3 then endurance for max HP and after that their main stat - super efficient

UPDATE:
If you want to nerd out on more specifics, I recommend **Section 7** of this [Fallout Shelter Efficiency Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/edit?pli=1#gid=0).

Also, here someone suggests that **skills above 10** continue to benefit the dweller/explorer:

- [Room efficiency data thread on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3a0p7v/room_efficiency_data_thread/)

---

Comment: Luck reduces the chance of a rush failure

Comment: Perception also reduces timer in water treatment plant.

Comment: Are you sure about endurance health and perception hit chance?

Comment: @glidud, unless the post is a community wiki, it is not acceptable to add information, unless it is yours. Post your addition as a comment, for OP to add, or add it as your own answer.

Comment: @Timelord64 In this case, the edit doesn't deviate from the intent of the post in any way, and is minor enough to be acceptable. The idea that one should copy this entire post but add one little point in your own answer is ridiculous, and is likely to get your new answer automatically flagged as a duplicate answer and deleted.

Comment: During combat (fighting off raiders/radroaches/mole rats), some dwellers seem to fire less frequently than others.  Could agility affect rate of fire?  (It does, after all, affect action points in the other Fallout games.)

Comment: @VGR Your "rate of fire" = my "hit chance in combat" under *Perception*. That's what I meant. Can't say for certain if agility helps, though. Been a long time since I played it now, hahas. Glad to see that my post has been positively received btw!

Comment: @SkyHiRider Funny you should mention the 2 particular traits I remember being pretty certain of. You can always experiment the hypotheses yourself.

Comment: One more thing Charisma helps with in the vault is the radio room, reducing the time needed to attract more Dwellers

Comment: I remember reading a reddit "scientist" finding out that endurance affects hp gain on level up (meaning you should, if possible, train newborns to E=10 immediately and give them a high-E outfit).

Comment: I feel like this _could_ be a great reference, but I wonder how many of these have actual testing to back them up. I notice, for example, that some seem to have come verbatim from a post in one of the reddit links prefixed by "If I had to guess based on the exploration events..." Hardly scientific.

Comment: Well it seems endurance effects the amount of hp you gain on lvl up. Dwellers start at 105 hp and gain (2.5 + 0.5 * endurance) hp per level. Wearing +7 endurance outfit increases the bonus, for a total of 11 hp per level and 644 hp at lvl 50 if dweller had 17 endurance on every lvl up.

Comment: I have read (and experience seems to confirm) that Luck affects *caps* in the wasteland; Perception affects *loot* in the wasteland. So you are far better off sending people out in a Sturdy Vault Suit (+5 Per) than a Formal Attire (+Luck).

Comment: I remember reading that Intelligence helps put out fires faster, but don't see a section in that spreadsheet that would even address it.

Comment: *something* (not sure what) seems to affect how fast the 'crit attempt' thing pulses (the thing that moves in and out for you to try to get a 5x)

Comment: also increases Exp gain (for level and Special stat increasing), distinguish fire
Do you have source for this? What is distinguish fire? extinguish?

Comment: Going to need another update for Quests.

Comment: Always good to have a fire distinguisher around. http://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/a8MjXz1_700b_v1.jpg

Comment: Can we also add that having someone in a vault room with a low corresponding stat increases risk of rush failure?

Answer (score 7):

Effects during quests only:

- Strength: Increased attack damage
- Perception: Reduced critical hit speed
- Endurance: Reduced radiation damage
- Charisma: Better dialogue choices
- Intelligence: Increased "this is the right/wrong way" frequency
- Agility: Reduced time between attack rounds
- Luck: Increased chance of critical hit

Answer (score 6):

*These are the other uses for S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats:*

- Strength: Damage increased everywhere.
- Perception: Damage increased in-Vault; better Loot in the Wasteland, and better Critical lock-on on Quests.
- Endurance: Increased health.
- Charisma: Helps charming Wasteland Creatures. (And eventually better results in dialouges on Quests.)
- Intelligence: Increased medical capacities in the Wasteland.
- Agility: Better Damage in-Vault, better Hit Speed on Quests, and less Damage from losing a combat in the Wasteland.
- Luck: Also gives better Loot on Quests and in the Wasteland.