# Can I prevent molerat attacks by surrounding all rooms with elevators?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The loading tooltip mentions that molerat attacks can only start in rooms touching dirt.  However, attacks do not start in elevators.  As such, can I make my vault molerat proof by completely surrounding it with elevators?

Comment: I'd suppose (although I have no real evidence for this), that even if you did that and it worked to prevent molerat attacks, fires and radroach infestations would each increase in frequency. I would think that room incidents (as opposed to bandit or deathclaw attacks) are defined by one set of rules which then selects which incident it is and removing the chances of one happening wouldn't reduce the number of incidents, just change which incident happened.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Since molerat attacks are the worst of incidents that can randomly occur within your vault, changing what incident happened would be a good thing.

Comment: @RossRidge that's really subjective. I keep all my dwellers armed to the teeth, so they take care of radroaches pretty fast. Raiders have the chance of stealing resources, so they are mildly worse IMO.

Comment: @TimS. **Molerats** are significantly worse than radroaches. Whether that means they wipe out multiple rooms in a single incident or just hurt your dwellers somewhat, it's worthwhile trying to minimize the number of these incidents, even if that means getting more radroach attacks. Raiders aren't a kind of incident that can randomly occur **within** your vault, and so aren't affected by this, but I'd also trade fewer molerat attacks for more raider attacks if I could. They're the easiest incident to deal with because you only need to arm one room to the teeth to deal with them.

Comment: Ah, I haven't played in a while, I didn't know about molerats... I was under the assumption that it was still only the 2 threats (raiders and radroaches).

Comment: @Tim S. For what it's worth, molerats can spread like radroaches and also destroy your resources like raiders.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, yes you can:
[image]

If you search through [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3iwzel/just_say_no_to_molerat_infestation/) you can see pretty extensive testing was done and seems to bear up that this does in fact work!

More testing on my own. When I get a "X fires" objective, I create a 'Sad Room' and put two of my best dwellers in there*. I recently got 'put out 47'. I thought I'd do some experimenting myself, so I built an elevator right next to it. I failed around 100 rushes on that room. I didn't count, but it was about half Radroaches half fires, and not one Molerat. I was half expecting the fact that the room below touches ground to be enough.

*After they've done their miserable tour, they get to run through every other room rushing once so they go back to 100% happiness.
[image: My 'Sad Room']

Comment: I hadn't suspected that someone would have already tried it!  I guess I'm behind the curve. Really great example of it, thanks!

Comment: Oh wow, impressive. I stand corrected. I tried to build a room under an elevator, but I didn't try to build one above. Nice!