# What benefits does a higher level dweller get?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When a dweller levels up, what actually changes? My thought at first was that they gain increased HP, but after reading [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/223912/86844) I noticed that HP seems to be controlled by Endurance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the **game's own wiki says levelling up a dweller actually increases his health points** and since there's no way to actually check how many health points a dweller has before and after levelling up, I'm just gonna trust the wiki :)

Also the wiki says the **endurance will help a dweller survive more in the wasteland**... this can be reflected by him having more health points **or** by him just **being less prone to lose health points** (so even though 2 dwellers have the same number of health points, the one with better endurance loses less health points when fight a rat, a scorpion or something like that)

**TL/DR: Levelling up increases health points, Endurance makes dweller lose less health points when fights a monster.**

Answer (score 6):

A side benefit of leveling up is that each subsequent level gains more caps. Leveling to 30 gives 30 caps, 31 gives 31 caps, etc.