# Does Luck improve the success rate of a Radio Station?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I know that the size of your radio room improves the chance of attracting a new dweller, and Charisma shortens the interval between checks, but does Luck have an effect? Since it helps with caps and rushing production in other rooms, it doesn't sound completely unlikely.

Comment: No is the answer I recall, I have to go hunting to find where I saw that though.

Comment: No, [see this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223904/what-does-each-special-stat-in-fallout-shelter-do)

Comment: Certainly not a duplicate. User is asking if luck can be used in the radio station. While the flagged duplicate might be considered to have the same answer, for some, it is the question being asked that constitutes a duplicate, not what the answer would be. @JonathanDrapeau, the answer to that question is very open, in terms of dealing with luck. In fact, luck is listed as helping with "Vault", and then the user proceeds to say "and also.. this". I can easily see why that would not confidently answer OPs question.

Comment: @Timelord64 I don't see how it doesn't answer this question. It states exactly what each stat does in the game, luck included. There's nothing that is missing in the other answer that would be helpful for this question. Even the current answer basically restate the same thing the linked question's answer says. That this question ask for a particular room adds nothing to what the stats do.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no.

Luck only modifies 3 things:

- Your chance of successfully rushing a room
- The amount of caps received for rushing a room/work completed
- Chances of finding gear out in the Wasteland.