# Does armor help explorers in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When equipping my explorers, I figured armor makes sense. But there doesn't seem to be an armor stat in the game. Does armor do anything different, or is it just a SPECIAL boost like other clothing?

Comment: All outfits boost SPECIAL stats, and each of these help adventurers in some way (though I don't know the specifics).  I think *Endurance* relates to hardiness, though.

Comment: @GnomeSlice There's [already an answer about the effects of SPECIAL on exploration](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223904/what-does-each-special-stat-in-fallout-shelter-do?rq=1). To be clear, I'm asking if armor does anything *beyond* SPECIAL. Is there a hidden armor stat?

Answer (score 5):

There is no armor stat.

Armor only works like clothing, in that it increases certain SPECIAL statistics.

That said, when equiptment insinuates a degree of protection, you should usually expect to see Endurance gain.