# How does Endurance and leveling up effect HP?

Tags: fallout-shelter

A friend of mine believes that you should fully train a Dweller's Endurance *before* you level them up, and that doing so will increase their final health. Meaning, a level 50 Dweller who trained Endurance after becoming level 50 would have a lower health than a level 50 Dweller who had dull Endurance before leveling.

I can't find anything about that [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/htmlview?pli=1&sle=true#). Any idea if that's true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does endurance over 10 increase HP gain per level?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235425/does-endurance-over-10-increase-hp-gain-per-level)

Comment: @Samthere, I disagree that it is a duplicate. The original question specifically asks if increasing endurance past 10 is effective on health gain, where this question is asking when the health gain is actually calculated. In fact, if they are both considered duplicates, this question has more votes, and both question and answer appear better formatted. I would say that under duplication argument, the other should be made a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 12):

A great deal of research has been done on it. [This thread has a lot of good information.](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3jzjr1/vault_dwellers_and_you_a_visual_guide_on/)

The short answer is, when your dweller levels up, the amount of HP they gain is based solely on Endurance at the time they do so. So being E10 w/ +7E gear will give the most HPs.

Once I get dwellers to E10 I equip my best Endurence gear (sadly not +7) and send them out until they are in danger of dying or find 'better' gear that isn't Endurance based.

Comment: Regardless of their other SPECIAL stats? You just send them out when they get to E10?

Comment: Sure. Until they are level 50. Usually only takes 3-4 trips with 25 stimpacks. And with E10 they don't need radaway.

Comment: Follow up note: Now that I've got a pretty decent amount of gear, I'm sending my highest SPECIAL person out w/ my +5E suit. Once they hit Level 50, the next one gets to go out.