# SPECIAL's effect during combat with DCs

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm trying to increase my resistance to Death Claws. Right now the balance is at a point where the DCs don't quite kill any of my Dwellers, but are able to get them to probably 10% health. They make it through three rooms with the most heavily armed Dwellers I have and then the DCs die.

One way to make sure my Dwellers survive is to maximize their health. I know that in order to reach maximum health you want to [level up Endurance as early as possible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235821/level-and-endurance-effects-on-heath). Another way to combat the DCs is to use powerful weapons, which I am collection through exploring as quickly as I can.

My main question is about various S.P.E.C.I.A.L. attributes and whether they have any effect *during* combat. The Perception training room is full of guns; does high Perception increase chance to hit? Does Strength act like Armour?

Obviously I would have every Dweller at full 10's across the board if I could. But since that takes way too long, what is actually going to help me during combat besides high health?