# Why do my maxed out dwellers get radiation damage in the wasteland?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a couple of dwellers with maxed out stats by now. When they go out to level up, they will not take red radiation damage for several days. The maximum I have so far managed was around five days without needing a radaway.

However, when I send the same dwellers out the second time when they are already 50, they get radiation damage. It's slow and not enough for them to use a radaway on two days, but there is red damage.

I assumed with Endurance on 10 that would not happen at all. Why are they not immune to radiation?

[image: dwellers with maximized stats gets radiation damage]

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/223904/20306)

Comment: @Unionhawk it's a duplicate if the information provided in the first answer is right : that 11 endurance is the value for a dweller being immune to radiation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only dwellers that have endurance stat ≥ 11 will be immune to radiation (see this related [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/223904/20306)).
Also: when a dweller levels up, he is completely healed (health and radiation).

Since level 50 is the max level, a dweller at that level cannot level up and therefore does not get the complete heal from a level up.

If you want your exploring dwellers to be immune to radiation, they have to have an endurance stat of ≥ 11. Training will only go to 10, but you can give them equipment that raises their stats over that.

Comment: Radiation is not healed when leveling up.