# How can I see my dweller's maximum HP?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I like to send out only dwellers with the highest HP into the Wasteland for the longest runs.  How can I see a dweller's actual HP?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to see a number for the dweller's health, but looks like the health increases with the level (and maybe Endurance?).

Anyway some guys are working on a [very useful google sheet for Fallout Shelters](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/edit#gid=1591448540).

On sheet 7, point 7.7 there is an experiment to try to calculate a Dweller's HP.

Comment: Yes, endurance does affect how much the max HP for a dweller goes up each time they level.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223904/what-does-each-special-stat-in-fallout-shelter-do  - And yes, the lack of a numeric value for the total HP for a dweller is something I lament the lack of.

Answer (score 4):

Without using a Save Editor of some kind there is no way to see your Dwellers' Max HP stat. However if you want a Wasteland Runner, you should at minimum raise Endurance to 10 before sending them out into the Wastes. If you can also equip them with +5 or +7 Endurance gear all the better. Whenever a dweller levels up they gain HP based on their Endurance, and this includes the gear they are wearing. So a Dweller who has a 17 in endurance will gain the most HPs each time she levels.

It's also worth noting that at 11 Endurance Dwellers don't take radiation damage in the wastes.

If you really want to do well in the wastes, raise all 7 stats to 10 before reaching Level 2. Then put your dweller in your best Endurance gear and send them out. Once they hit Level 50, switch to your best other gear and give a newbie the high Endurance gear. There are events for each of the stats in the wastes, so having everything maxed will give you the best benefit. Additionally, when a Dweller levels up they are healed completely, so a SPECIAL 10 dweller w/ Endurance gear can often go a whole day or two before using her first Stimpack. I've had several dwellers make it 5 days or more before running out of Stimpacks.

Comment: Yes, I understand how Endurance works and have instituted a comprehensive exercise program, but not everyone got the training at level 1 so I've lost track. Also, I don't mind peeking with a save game utility.

Comment: In my when someone gets to E10 I append their name with •## (where ## is what level they are) so I know what level they finished their E training in.

Comment: I don't level E on any dweller who gets past level 1. New level 1 dwellers get sent to Fitness training, and then, with 10E, are used in my vault. As I get the gear, 10E/1 dwellers are sent into the wasteland and levelled there, to 50, in wasteland gear. When they return, I use the Barber, to color their hair according to the quality of the wasteland gear they levelled in: +3E gets green hair, +5E gets blue hair, +7E gets purple hair.