# Which outfit should I use for vault entrance guards?

Tags: fallout-shelter

- I have couple of dwellers Guarding the entrance. I want to know which
  outfit I need to use for these dwellers.
- I am organizing all the
  rooms in such a way that each and every dweller is having a weapon &
  the correct outfit.
- But I am confused with this vault entrance guards?
- Is there any particular S.P.E.C.I.A.L stats that will be useful to
  them to do their job better? Please clarify.
- Also please clarify if there is any other way to assign guards for
  the vault.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223904/what-does-each-special-stat-in-fallout-shelter-do) and assuming your guard dwellers are already level 50, only two S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats should be relevant for vault entrance guards.

**Perception**

> Hit chance in combat

**Agility**

> Attack speed.

These are the only relevant stats which have an influence on your fighting skill inside the vault, and there is nothing else the dwellers are useful for at entrance.

The only purpose of your dwellers here is to clear all threats (raiders and deathclaws) as quickly as possible, so I would give them jumpsuits for agility or heavy raider armor for agility and perception and also the best weapons you have (except the ones your dwellers in the wasteland use). If you have no good agility suits or want to to prefer Perception, the (armored/sturded/heavy) vault suits should be your first choice.

If they are not level 50, you could think about also giving them some suits with endurance, so they increase their maximum life and don't die during each deathclaw attack.

You can only assign two dwellers to the entrance room, so they are the only "guards" inside the vault, but it is a common tactic to also put max level dwellers with good weapons in the room(s) right behind the entrance, so they eliminate all threats your entrance guards could not kill.

Comment: +1. A heavy vault suit also gives you +7 to a combination of perception and agility, +7 to perception, specifically. Here's a list of outfits: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_outfits

Comment: @dcshannon:you are correct, but i would personally concentrate more on agilty, because i would guess  attack-speed to eliminate threats is more important,but maybe i am wrong about it.at least if you have no agilty outfits that would be the best alternative

Comment: I will add this alternative to my answer tommorow, thank you

Comment: Greater attack speed and greater chance to hit would both increase the number of hits over time. Which one is better would depend on the exact numbers involved for each bonus.