# Does a dweller's outfit affects their training time?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Okay, so a dweller's Intelligence affects how fast he/she can be trained.

Does this depend on the dweller's "native" Intelligence level (the green bar/number), or can I have him/her put on, say a Lab Coat, to make the training faster?

Comment: I'm not finding anywhere that says intelligence affects how fast they can be trained.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Seems to be from the latest patch.  My dummies now take over 20 hours for their final stat point.

Comment: @TimmyJim someone else once shared that: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/223912/79770

Comment: Intelligence does NOT influence how fast dwellers can be trained, except when you train their intelligence. The higher the SPECIAL stat of your dweller you train, the longer it takes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily tested.  I put on some +4 Int clothing on a dweller, made them leave the room, and put them back in.  Did not change the training time.

I do not have reliable training testing with native INT stat.  I'll need to get some fresh dwellers to test.